# That's Ounce Weird

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

I am alone in a room. The room is very quiet, except that one may hear a sound of something like snowing, and a sound of something resembling a cloak. In the next room behind the door, there’s also a persistent sound of something akin to an abyss.

Suddenly, there's a sound of something close to a lamb. I jump up and run to the next room.

What’s going on?

Hint #1:

> This is a very casual situation for almost any person.

Hint #2:

> The abyss is treacherous and doesn't follow the rules.

Hint #3:

> What could be in the next room? What kind of a persistent sound could I hear? Why did I run there?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to the solution, but the title is a rot13(znq tno bs "gung fbhaqf jrveq")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicolas Budig’s answer was the closest to the truth, but still not complete. So I decided to answer my own question:

The title, "That’s Ounce Weird",

> sounds like "that sounds weird", which is the key to most parts of the puzzle.

"snowing" is

> snoring, because I was sleeping

"a cloak" is

> a ticking clock

"An abyss", maybe the least obvious part, refers to…

> "a drop", which may be a drop into an abyss, but also a drop of water. So the persistent sound of "an abyss" refers to a sound of a leaking tap in the bathroom. The abyss is "treacherous" in the sense that it doesn’t follow the wordplay.

"a lamb" is

> the alarm clock ringing

"I jump up and run to the next room", because…

> it’s time to go work, so I run to the bathroom to take a shower.

Comment: 'A drop of water' is extremely far from 'something akin to an abyss' imo.. especially considering the fact that A) this one hint doesn't follow the format of the other clues/title, and B) unlike the other clues, a leaky tap is a not a common thing and it definitely isn't a thing that you would normally associate with the sleeping theme. All things considered, I don't think it's very realistic to expect people to figure it out based on what you've given.

Comment: @votbear probably so, this is also why I decided to provide the answer. Although I still think this was doable, considering all the hints.

Answer (score 11):

I think

> You are sleeping and an alarm goes off, making you run into the next room

Reasoning:

> as @Riley said, the title sounds like "that sounds weird" when spoken aloud

so taking that theme,

> something like snowing -> snoring 
> something resembling a cloak -> a clock 
> something akin to an abyss -> haven't figured this out yet :( 
> something close to a lamb -> alarm

Comment: Not sure, but if wordplay is applicable, 'akin to an abyss' can mean 'near to engulf'...Which can be done by natural elements like water, fire etc.

Comment: Correct! The similarity of “abyss” is of a different kind.

Comment: Not sure why it’s in the next room, but could he be late to catch “a bus” (abyss)?

Comment: The ”persistent” bit in the clue might refer to a continuing action, which would then make ROT13(”naq n ohmmvat”) the most likely solution.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay your reasoning is wrong, but otherwise you're very close. I've added a couple of hints.

Comment: Perhaps the sibilant ending is onomatopoeic of gas escaping? Hence "treacherous".

Comment: @Lawrence an interesting take, but no, this isn't about onomatopoeia.

Comment: Maybe "something akin to an abyss" is yawning (a la "a yawning abyss"). Could be a morning scene and the alarm indicates that breakfast is served! Though for some reason, I am also considering that there is a baby sleeping in the other room and the "alarm" is either the baby crying, or an actual alarm that someone forgot to turn off and that will wake the baby, hence the urgency.  But I can't quite make that one match the existing clues.

Answer (score 0):

The sound of the 'cloak' is

> clothing

and the 'abyss' represents

> the inside of the washing machine, which buzzes when it's done with its cycle?

Furthermore, the title is a reference to

> the units (in the United States) in which laundry detergent is sold.

Comment: Nope, but this is close in a certain sense.